# when i insert data these error was appear (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: flutter, sqflite

insert(CartProductModel cartProductModel) async {
Database? Mydatabase = await database;

```
    int response = await Mydatabase!.insert(
        "products", cartProductModel.tojson(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    print(" insert $response") ;

return response;
```

}

Comment: Try replacing first line

      int response = await Mydatabase?.insert(

Comment: try it but get me error

Comment: By looking at your error it seems that your Mydatabase is null..... Are you calling a static method on Mydatabase or is your Mydatabase variable an object??